# Can a development class from one Composer library be used in a development class from a different Composer library?

Tags: composer-php

I have a useful class in the dev section of one library that I'd like to use in the dev section of a second library without copying the class over.

If I do `composer require --dev my/library` it moves the whole library to the dev section, making it unavailable to the live code.

The only way I've though of being able to do this is to manually edit the `autoload-dev` section in `composer.json` to point that class to the correct `vendor` directory. This works, but it feels like the wrong way to do it.

Is there a recommended way to tell Composer to make the development classes from one Composer library available to a different Composer development class?

Answer (score 0):

There is no clean way, sadly.

The only way is the one you mentioned. Point to the vendor folder in the `autoload-dev` section of your `composer.json` file, e.g.:

```
"autoload-dev": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Other\\Library\\Tests\\": "vendor/other/library/tests"
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Anything "dev" in Composer is ignored if a package is used inside another package.

If you have a useful class in one of your libraries and want to use it, you must expose it as "production" code, not "dev", including non-dev autoloading.

You should be able to create another library that only contains your useful dev-classes, and then `require --dev` this library everywhere else.

Pointing the autoloader deeply inside the vendor folder may work, but I'd consider this a bad hack, not a solution. It will break if you rename a folder in that lib.